# textboxes with value

Tags: jquery

I have page with 3 textbox. I to find all textboxes which have value into it and print its text. How to do?

Comment: I want to array only those textbox which have value in it

Comment: Textboxes can either be `textarea` or `input type="text"`. You need both or one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code to fetch all the values of the  in a page which are not empty:

```
$('input[type=text][value!=]').each( function() { 
    var value = $(this).val();
    // do whatever you want with the value
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I gess that you need either

```
$("input[type=text]").val();
```

or

```
$("textarea").val();
```

Most likely, you will need both, so

```
$("input[type=text][value!=] textarea[value!=]").val();
```

would search the contents of all non empty elements on your page a user can insert text into.

Answer (score 0):

Use [selector/text](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/text) and [selectors/attributeNotEqual](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeNotEqual#attributevalue).

```
$("form input:text[value!=]").each(function() {
  $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':text').each(function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input').each(function(){
    alert(this.value);
});
```